# how to make popover placement set to below instead of right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

what is wrong with my syntax i cant get it to display below. by default the popover is set to display right. i want to change this to display below. according to the documentation, i need to write placement below. but it isnt working.

```
   $("a[rel=popover1]")
  .popover({placement:'below'})
  .click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  })
```

Comment: its not working in the example either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be `bottom` not below if you're using [bootstrap-popover.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers).

http://jsfiddle.net/5DGef/15/

```
$(function() {
    $('a[rel=popover]').popover({placement:'bottom'});
});​
```

Comment: that worked. i should have checked the js file because it does say below, the reason i thought bottom is because on the bootstrap website under options it says bottom.